# how to list of file and folder display from the skydrive in uitableview using objective c

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, onedrive

I am new iPhone developer.in my app sky-drive integration there but i am don't know sky-drive integration.

I need your help to solve my problem.

how can do this.

I am try this demo

Link:
https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-iOS

but It is run in my iphone but I can not Login sky-drive account.

here https://account.live.com/ login my account and registration my app. than get the 
Client ID  and Client secret. than put the Client ID in my code.

how to list of file and folder in uitableview.

all step are follows but I cant not access my sky-drive account.

so, places suggestion me code or demo example or link's.

Answer (score 0):

As for the live-sdk sample: did you put your client-id like it is shown on picture?
[image]

Then the sample code should work.

Now if you want to browse files, please, **[see my repo](https://github.com/braveS/APOneDriveWrapper)**.

Ask, if you have some questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the demo app which I have created. Should help you because I have completed with some additional changes.

https://github.com/ashishuniyal3/OneDrive.git .